# Mongo query is taking a while even with index

Tags: mongodb

I have been running a mongo test server for a few weeks now and everything has been going good. I had a query to get a count of deleted files and it was running in the sub 1 second range for 140 million documents (44 gb of data). Today, all of the sudden that same query is taking a while. When running explain on the find query it shows it is using the index that is in place but it still takes a long time. The weird thing is, is that this isn't the only query that appears to do this. If I run a query that returns 1 item, it's almost instantaneous. When its returning a set of documents it takes forever (multiple minutes).  Below is the query and the explain output from Mongo shell. I've removed the rejected plan to save space, but can put it back if needed. I'm new to mongo so any help is greatly appreciated. I have another query that I've been waiting on for 24 minutes that is just a search on an EventID field which is an indexed field.

```
 db.EventEntries.find({IsDelete:true, TimeCreated:{$gte:ISODate('2017-06-30')}}).explain('executionStats')
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "Events.EventEntries",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "IsDelete" : {
                                            "$eq" : true
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "TimeCreated" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00Z")
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : 1,
                                    "TimeCreated" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "IsDelete_1_TimeCreated_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : [ ],
                                    "TimeCreated" : [
                                            "TimeCreated"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : [
                                            "[true, true]"
                                    ],
                                    "TimeCreated" : [
                                            "[new Date(1498780800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            },

    },
    "executionStats" : {
            "executionSuccess" : true,
            "nReturned" : 138570,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 177933,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 138570,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 138570,
            "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "nReturned" : 138570,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 177834,
                    "works" : 138571,
                    "advanced" : 138570,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 8887,
                    "restoreState" : 8887,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 138570,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 138570,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 561,
                            "works" : 138571,
                            "advanced" : 138570,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 8887,
                            "restoreState" : 8887,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : 1,
                                    "TimeCreated" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "IsDelete_1_TimeCreated_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : [ ],
                                    "TimeCreated" : [
                                            "TimeCreated"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "IsDelete" : [
                                            "[true, true]"
                                    ],
                                    "TimeCreated" : [
                                            "[new Date(1498780800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 138570,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 138570,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                            "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
            }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "",
            "port" : ,
            "version" : "3.4.4",
            "gitVersion" : "888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd"
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Comment: If the query is fast for a single value but slow for a larger range of values an obvious suspicion would be that you are limited by server resource (I/O or RAM). How much RAM do you have on your server and how large are the indexes? Is 44GB the `dataSize` (actual data) or `storageSize` (size on disk, which may include compression)? Do you have other databases in the same MongoDB deployment? Also, how long does the query take to execute if you immediately run the same query again?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I rebuilt the index and it failed so I started from scratch. But it could have been a ram issue. Since it's a test vm it only had 3.5 gb of ram.

Comment: 3.5 GB of total RAM sounds very low for your data size and the range queries you are running. Check `db.EventEntries.stats().totalIndexSize` for the size of indexes for this collection. By default WiredTiger in MongoDB 3.4 will allocate [50% of RAM - 1GB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#to-what-size-should-i-set-the-wiredtiger-internal-cache) for the internal cache (indexes and uncompressed data) which should be roughly 750MB in your case. Your range query returns 138,570 documents and will put more pressure on your limited resources than an equality query for a single document.